# Как полностью заменить содержание коллекции?

Tags: java, hibernate

Здравствуйте.
Есть БД mysql, есть две таблицы Parent и Child с отношением OneToMany.
Есть родитель с коллекцией List = {"a","b","c","d"}. 
В приведенном ниже методе я вставляю туда значения "x","y","z".
Нужен результат "x","y","z" а получается "a","b","c","d","x","y","z"

```
public static void insertPoint(long parent_id){
   Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
   Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
   Query query = session.createQuery("from Parent where id= :id");
   query.setLong("id", parent_id);

   Parent parent = (Parent) query.uniqueResult();
   List<Child> new_children = new LinkedList<>();
   new_children.add("x");
   new_children.add("y");
   new_children.add("z");
   parent.setChildren(new_children);

   session.update(parent);
   //session.merge(parent);

   tx.commit();
   session.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так:

```
public static void insertPoint(long parent_id){
   ........
   Parent parent = (Parent) query.uniqueResult();
   List<Child> new_children = new LinkedList<>();
   List<Child> old_children = parent.getChildren();
   new_children.add("x");
   new_children.add("y");
   new_children.add("z");
   parent.setChildren(new_children);


   session.update(parent);
   tx.commit();
   session.close();

   for(Child ch : old_children){
      deleteChild(ch.getId());
   }
}
```

но наверное это должно делаться иначе.

Answer (score 0):

Операции с сущностями `JPA/Hibernate` зачастую схожи с `SQL`-операциями. У вас 2 задачи:

1. Добавить новые элементы в коллекцию `children` (`SQL INSERT`)
2. Удалить ранее существовавшие элементы коллекции `children` (`SQL DELETE`)

Коллекция `children` создаётся `Hibernate`-ом при чтении `parent` из БД, `Hibernate` отслеживает операции с коллекцией. Для того, чтобы решить *задачу 1* следует обращаться к методу `parent.getChildren().add()`, а для решения *задачи 2* - `parent.getChildren().remove()`, или для Вашего случая - `parent.getChildren().removeAll()`. При сохранении `parent`-а `Hibernate` выполнит запросы `SQL INSERT` и `SQL DELETE` в соответствии с операциями, выполненными с коллекцией.
Код получится примерно такой:

```
//отдаём команду удаления всех существующих элементов
parent.getChildren().removeAll()
//добавляем новые элементы
parent.getChildren().add("x");
parent.getChildren().add("y");
parent.getChildren().add("z");
//отдаём команду выполнить изменения в БД
session.update(parent);
```